# How to change HTTP Status Code in WSO2 ESB REST API

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a rest api created using WSO2 ESB. 
I want to change the HTTP status code to 404 when the requested API resource does not match with the given URL. 
Currently I am getting a 'HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted' response. 
My esb version is 4.0.3.

Comment: I follwed the tutorial here but it didn't worked for me. http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2012/11/tip-error-handling-in-wso2-esb-apis.html.                                                                                                     I want a similar solution.

Answer (score 14):

Try with `<property name="HTTP_SC" value="404" scope="axis2"/>`

Comment: It is same as in link provided by author of topic, and sometimes setting property HTTP_SC ignored by synapse.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [wso2 documentation](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/rest_api_examples/setting-https-status-codes/)

```
<outSequence>
                 <property name="HTTP_SC" value="404" scope="axis2" />
                 <send/>
</outSequence>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

The thing is when the URL is incorrect the request will not enter your code and will be answered by WSO2 ESB/EI itself. So in your code you don't have influence on the response in that case. Maybe it can be configured in WSO2 itself, can't find any on that yet.